# css property - bottom not work on grid container which is position:fixed

Tags: css, grid

I have set up a container which covers the whole screen via

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The problem is if I change property - bottom to another value, it does not affect the display.

```js
function toggle(){
  var container = document.querySelector(".container");
  container.classList.toggle("pull-down");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container.pull-down {
  bottom: -100px;
}

div {
  pointer-events: none;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 40px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>first row</div>
  <div>second row</div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle</button>
```

What I expect is that if a user clicks the button, the second row will move out of the screen.

The behavior on FF is correct but not on chrome version - 78.0.3904.108.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems a bug because if you resize the screen it works. You can add something to your script to force the page refresh:

```js
function toggle(){
  var container = document.querySelector(".container");
  container.classList.toggle("pull-down");
  
  /* Force page redraw*/
  container.style.display="none";
  setTimeout(function(){container.style.display="grid"},1);
  /* */
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container.pull-down {
  bottom: -100px;
}

div {
  pointer-events: none;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 40px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>first row</div>
  <div>second row</div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, I also think that should be a bug. Your workaround can make it happen, but I can notice a flash between display: none and display: grid. I can eliminate the flicker by setting right to 1px and reverting it to 0. But neither the workarounds can achieve a transition based on the property - bottom.

Comment: @krave use this link to report the bug: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines and since it's a bug I don't think you will be able to have transition